# "I expect he will know" vs. "I expect he knows"

Tags: modal-verbs, verb-usage

I understand that *will* can be used to refer to the likelihood of a future event, for example:

> I expect (that) she won't like the news

Source: Merriam-Websters Advanced Learners English Dictionary

But what I do not get is why the writer chose to use *will* with *expect* in the context below

> The past tense may sometimes occur in the if clause (If I knew you
>   were coming . . .), but in British English, at least, it would be
>   unusual. That said, I **expect** some of us **will know** the song that has
>   the line If I knew you were coming, I’d have baked a cake.

Source: [“If I knew you're coming I wouldn't have come”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/47124/if-i-knew-youre-coming-i-wouldnt-have-come)

I expected him to write the sentence below, since he already knows the song he mentioned.

> That said, I **expect** some of us <strike>will</strike> know the song

Answer (score 2):

We can use 'will' in a statement about a event or situation to indicate that we are fairly, or nearly, certain that it is true.

> Will
>   *2 used for showing that you are fairly certain that something is true*
>   Most of you will know about the problems we’ve been having.
>   There’s the doorbell. That’ll be Janet.

[Will (Macmillan Dictionary)](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/will_1)

Comment: I see you got an answer as 'AntiScam' on Word Reference earlier today, but at least we give you a dictionary link.

Comment: Thanks, Michael. Much appreciated. And I think your comment with "at least" is just one reason why I do that! I even keep the same title more often than not, and it is no secret nor is it in violation with both sites policies.